# loop to check for issues

Tags: python-3.x, jira

i have this small program to assign issues to me, it works great on pycharm but when i compile it to exe with pyintaller it closes after the first run, ignoring the time.sleep and running again creating a loop to check for issues every 5 seconds.

why is that? how can i fix it?

```
import time
import winsound
from jira import JIRA

global lst_ignore
issue_var = ""
lst_ignore = []

def jira_login():
    global user,token
    user = 'user@cloud.com'
    token = 'kj432hj43214YMzCyMLOe7682'

    try:
        options = {'server': 'https://cloud.atlassian.net'}
        global jira
        jira = JIRA(options=options, basic_auth=(user, token))



    except Exception as e:
         jira = ""
         if '401' in str(e):
            print("Login to JIRA failed. Check your username and password",e)

    return jira


def check_issue():
    jira_login()
    size = 100000
    start = 0 * 100000

    search_query = 'status not in (Done, Closed,Canceled) and assignee is EMPTY and project = "Success" and reporter not in (57f778:f48131cb-b67d-43c7-b30d-2b58d98bd077)'

    issues = jira.search_issues(search_query, start, size)

    for issue in issues:
        if issue not in lst_ignore:
            winsound.Beep(2000, 1000)
            issue.update(assignee={'accountId': '60f1d072a0de61930ad83770'})
            print(issue, " : assinged to you!")
            lst_ignore.append(issue)
   


def check():
    check_issue()
    time.sleep(5)
    check()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    check()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW ANSWER:___________________________________________________

(New info obtained from comment) If it says you don't have the module when running from the console, but it does from Pycharm, you probably have 2 different Interpreters. There are two steps you must take.

1. Using the terminal run: pip install jira
2. If it says it is already installed, uninstall using pip, and then reinstall.

Good Luck!

OLD ANSWER:____________________________________________________

It is hard to say. One thing I can tell you is that a recursive function is almost never a good idea.

So instead of:

```
def check():
    check_issue()
    time.sleep(5)
    check()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    check()
```

Try the following aproach:

```
RUNNING = True
def main():
    while RUNNING:
        check_issue()
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After that you can implement that if some condition is met, it wil change the RUNNING constant to exit the program. Or, if it is a console-run program, then just use a keyboard-interrupt

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatly it does the same thing. open and close

Comment: Then I'd reccomand providing some more info in your original question. I also can't help but wonder what is the difference between your PyCharm Envirement and the compiled version. If you run the .py file straight from the terminal instead of from PyCharm, does it work then? Otherwise I'd be looking at the compiler for errors

Comment: PS C:\Users\Ricardo Simões\PycharmProjects\jira_unassign> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ricardo Simões\PycharmProjects\jira_unassign\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from jira import JIRA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jira'

Comment: but i have jira installed :s

Comment: I think I know the issue. You probebly have a different interpreter on pycharm and your local interpreter. To fix it look at my edited Answer

Comment: No problem, Good luck with the project!

Comment: Could have swear i reply to this, got it fix, installed jira outside pycharm and it worked, thanks JLT